# Testing a laravel controller - Faking a Illuminate\Http\Request

Tags: php, laravel, faker

I have a controller which is getting an instance of *`Illuminate\Http\Request`* injected through the constructor. Now I need to write an unit test that test a call in the controller which uses the values from the `Request` instance. I have decided to use `Faker`. How to use Faker to generate an associative array so that I can use the array in my test case like,

`$this->post('the_uri','MyFakerArray')`

And the dynamic array will automatically be available in my controllers request.

Comment: The best way for you is to "study" other project that is on github and also have tests (for me I look a lot at entrust by zizaco, but there is many many packages for laravel). Another way is to go to laracast and see testing section. (I am experimenting with tests myself)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no need to fake/mock the Request object.
When you are simulating a request laravel does that for you, it create a request to the url you request and pass the variables, then you get back the response from your application.

For example:

```
$response = $this->call('POST', '/user', ['name' => 'Taylor']);
```

now the `$response` variable has the data to test on.

I think you have:

```
 getContent() // for getting the reponse body
 getCode()    // for http code: 200, 401 etc
```

When you do that, your tests should work with the response, you have no need for Faker in this situation.